# iframe app profile not visible after setting app up @ developer.facebook.com

Tags: facebook, iframe

I recently built a simple app to display a custom tab on a client's business fan page, but after setting the app up and then checking the insights link, the link that normally appears called 'Visit App Profile Page' does not appear on the left menu (as it has previously).

I have built apps since Oct 1, so I'm fairly sure I have correctly accounted for the SSL requirement, but I have run out of ideas on how to troubleshoot this problem.

Any suggestions?

thanks,

Neil Heird

Answer (score 0):

You can create it manually if you need it since Facebook is planing on removing them. Read this blog post - http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ .